# Video Input Out of Range

Tags: windows, windows-xp, display, resolution

I tried to change the screen resolution because it was hurting my eyes but now the computer has a video input problem that says "out of range" and dv1 selection.

What I'm seeing:

[image]

Comment: Wait for 30 seconds. If nothing happens restart. Try again with a lower resolution and/or refresh rate.

Answer (score 1):

1) Start your computer
2) Before you get the XP boot logo press F8 to get the startup options
3) Select to start Windows in VGA mode by selecting "`Enable VGA Mode`".

This will force XP to boot to 800x600 (or 640x480). You can then choose an appropriate resolution to restore your display to normal.

Comment: @Psycogeek That is a VERY old link... note its talking about windows 98 and ME...

Comment: Safe Mode loads a basic set of services and drivers to help you regain control of Windows. Completely separate to VGA mode. VGA mode overrides any resolution set that may cause you to not be able to see Windows - I.e. exactly what the OP is experiencing. VGA mode still runs Windows as a full startup (not selective, such as Safe Mode). All Windows versions have this ability from XP and higher,  I believe? Can't remember if 2000 and earlier had it - that long ago!