# My Hp compaq cq57 windows 7 wont show a startup screen after installing the recommended graphics drivers

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, graphics-card

I recently cleaned installed windows 7 64bit on my hp compaq cq57 laptop. 
When I try to install the hp recommended graphics driver to the system, it installs but on restart, the system does not show the login screen after showing the windows logo. It just shows black screen. What is the cause of this problem and how do I solve it?

**Update:** Like I said before, all the drivers are working correctly except the graphics driver which seems to install correctly. The problem happens when it restarts to complete the installation of the driver. When it gets to the point where it suppose to show the login screen, all I get is a dead screen, and am sure the my systems graphics is working properly because i have checked it using gpu-z tool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Video Input Out of Range](http://superuser.com/questions/770516/video-input-out-of-range) - the same steps apply for Windows 7

Comment: Hi, @BigChris I just tried the solution given to the 'Video Input  Out of Range', its not working.